# testing an nfc application

Tags: test-design, mobile

My company is currently developing a Near Field Communication(NFC) based application. What test scenarios need to be checked for NFC-based applications? How do I test the applications which use NFC?

What kind of tools need to be used for testing NFC-based applications? For blackberry devices I used the following [link](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/testing_nfc_applications_1627604_11.html)

Please share your suggestions, application checklist for NFC-based applications on NFC-enabled devices. Googling hasn't helped me.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314569/how-to-test-nfc-api

Comment: Will this be a desktop application or phone app? Clearly you'll have to use some kind of NFC reader which reads the data from the NFC tag. You'll have to then make sure that the data being read is the expected data and nothing else.

Comment: Nitin, I agree with your last couple sentences, but I kind of feel that's a given. I think the OP is really asking about how to achieve those goals. Could you expand on specifics about how you'd go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

> When testing NFC components or devices, both analog (RF) and digital
>   (protocol) tests must be performed. Analog tests measure such things
>   as power levels, waveform quality, frequency accuracy, and modulation,
>   while digital tests check for things like low-layer protocol
>   exchanges, link timings and framing, as well as higher level protocols
>   layers like Logical Link Control Protocol (LLCP) and Simple NDEF
>   Exchange Protocol (SNEP).

Please go through this [pdf](http://literature.cdn.keysight.com/litweb/pdf/5991-2738EN.pdf) for more info.

Some more links which may be of some help are:

[Test considerations for NFC enabled devices in manufacturing](http://www.litepoint.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/NFC_Whitepaper_021814.pdf) - A Whitepaper.

[Near Field NFC Tester (an android app)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.promethylhosting.nfc.test&hl=en)

[7 Misconceptions About NFC Testing](http://www.eetimes.com/author.asp?doc_id=1324887)

[How can I test the NFC capability of my Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37936/how-can-i-test-the-nfc-capability-of-my-android)

[How To Have Fun with Near Field Communication on Android](http://www.tested.com/tech/android/2234-how-to-have-fun-with-near-field-communication-on-android/)

Comment: Your links produce a 404 error.